# Handling Server side data processing and request time-outs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server, request

Suppose we have a system where the user can uploaded a CSV form the front-end, and for example this CSV has close to a 1000 records, now on the backend I would grab the posted values, loop over them, and add the records in the database. So my question is, What is the best way to handle server-side request where you have a server time-out and need to process a large amount of data. What would be the best way to handle requests that require some time to be procced on the backend.

In past for these kind of problems, what I did was processed the data on the front-end (basically bricking records in individual rows/items) and looped over them, and made ajax calls for individual record but this approach also had its on set of problems, so what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: If you do something long time running, use a queue system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.